# How to create search tab and open the .txt file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create a search tab that contains a lot of options. when the user select an option, that option will open a file which saved as a .txt file. I use jQuery mobile.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/interface.min.css" />
    <link href="css/style-slide.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropdownPlain.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-page{
        background: transparent url(cute.png);
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" class="type-home" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
<center><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="100" alt="name" /></center>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<div class="content-primary">   
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-filter-placeholder="What do you want to search?"/>
                <li><a href="saya.txt">Apa khabar</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div><!--/content-primary -->      
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi; it's not very clear what exactly you're asking. You should post some of your code (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); you may also want to rephrase the question to state the problem you're having more clearly.

Comment: What are you using as a search system? SQL `LIKE/=`? Database free text search? A search system like Lucene?

Comment: How are you rendering your search results? Is this a `<form>` with a regular page round-trip to the server? Or does this use jQuery Mobile? If the latter, please add your JavaScript. As it stands there is no detail here for someone to assist with - so please answer all of these questions, in the body of the question itself.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how to insert my actual code here.

Comment: @Aliah: paste it into the question, select it, and press the 'code' button. It will indent everything four spaces, and will automatically render as preformatted code. See [my edit here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25217222/revisions).

Comment: OK, good edit, though we'll still need to know what form your data is stored in, and what search system you plan to use. See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you have to save the path of the text file in the value of the option in select and may be you can do this dynamically 
as below

```
  <select id="myselect">
    <option value="url_to_text_file_on_server">link</option>
</select>
```

then to open the text file you can use the window.location of javascript for opening the html file as below

```
$("#myselect").change(function(){
  window.location = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();
});
```

[jsFiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmmqvu89/1/) See this for live demo

**UPDATE**

To add a select widget to your page, start with a standard select element populated with a set of option elements. Set the for attribute of the label to match the ID of the select so they are semantically associated. Wrap them in a div with the data-role="fieldcontain" attribute to help visually group it in a longer form.

for jquery mobile
html part

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="myselect" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
        <select name="myselect" id="myselect">
          <option value="url_to_text_file_on_server">link</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

script should go in document ready function in the botton

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myselect").on("change",function(){
  window.location = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks. but which place that i had to put this code?

Comment: see the update for your query

Comment: this code is for selected option right? I want to make it in search tab.